# How wait/notify and Condition manage threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I understand that the `wait()` and `notify()/notifyAll()` methods serve the purpose of replacing the traditional looping/polling constructs used in other languages:

```
while(true) {
    if(pollSomethingForAnEvent())
        break;
}
```

I further understand that the `Condition` API was introduced in Java 5 to be wrap this model in a more "OO" implementation.

What I **don't understand** is how Java knows which threads to notify when `Object.notify()` or `Condition.signal()` is called, or how Java knows which threads to signal with `Object.wait()` or `Condition.await()` is called?

Since these methods don't take anything as parameters, how does the JVM know which threads to pass these notifications to?!?!

Comment: Generally, if only one thread is being awoken, it's first come first served. That is, the first thread to have executed the wait command with be the first to be notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each `Condition` or synchronized object, the JVM maintains a queue of objects that are waiting on them.  It also has run queues and other data structures which maintain and manage the `Thread` run states.

When `Object.notify()` is called, it just looks in the queue associated to the object at takes the first `Thread` there and moves it to the run queue.  If the queue is empty then no threads are notified.  If `notifyAll()` is called then all threads that are waiting on that object are signaled.

Not to complicate matters, but one thing that is important to realize is that when a `Thread` that called `lockObject.wait()`is notified, it moves from a wait state to the *end* of the run queue waiting to get access to the lock on `lockObject`.  It does not start running immediately.